# WADL in a native JAX-RS application?

Tags: jax-rs

we used to Jersey (https://jersey.java.net/)as an implementation of JAX-RS. **Now**, we use native JAX-RS WebSphere 8.5.

Is there a way to **automatically** get WADL of the JAX-RS application?

Comment: Check [this out](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_wadl_serving.html). Not portable, but uses WebSphere's implementation (Apache Wink)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. We do not want to migrate our apps. We can use apache wink. But in our code we do not want any apache wink imports. It is possible?

Comment: There is no JAX-RS specific way to do this.  Each way is implementation specific.